# How to analyze errors in jmeter load test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I ran a sample test in Jmeter non-GUI mode and a transaction failed for few iterations. When I opened the the jtl report in View Results Tree listener, for the failed sampler I got 'No data to display' message. Not only this, but for all the samplers the same message was displayed.

1. Here I want to see what the request was and what was the response. How to get those details?
2. And also all the samplers are jumbled so it is very difficult to identify which iteration failed. Is there a way to get all the requests in an orderly manner?
   [image: Below is how my listener looks line]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the listener [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) you can save the failed responses to a folder and analyse that after your test. You can put variables (like ${__threadNum}) into the filename field to provide more information like iteration or user.